# Making Child Divs fit inside parent Div neatly

Tags: html, css

Sorry ahead of time, as I have been at a loss of what question to ask to even start working toward the solution.

I've been trying to find a way to make objects (div, img, etc) with margins to compact inside the parent div. At first I thought float would solve all my problems but I'm new to this and quickly realized that it wouldn't

This leaves lots of ugly space. The divs that exceed the row drop down to the next line and base their height off of the bottom of the div above them.

Does anyone know of a way with either html, css, or J script to circumvent this? There isn't a whole lot of constraints. Also in practice use I would have all the child divs with their own id's, this was just to simplify.

```
#parent {
height: 600px; width:600px;
}
.childsmall
{
     background-color:#0F0; height: 100px; width: 100px; float: left; margin: 10px;
}
.childmed
{
background-color:#0FF; height: 150px; width: 150px; float: left; margin: 10px;
}
.childlarge
{
background-color:#000; height: 200px; width: 200px; float: left; margin: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childmed"></div>
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childlarge"></div>
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childmed"></div>
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childsmall"></div>
    <div class="childmed"></div>
    <div class="childlarge"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some JavaScript "magic" for what you want to achieve. Check this out: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply, this looks promising but I need to sleep 3:35 am zZzZ I'll give this a shot first thing when I wake up.